# ImportError: DLL load failed, while file is in working directory

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to import scanpy for use in jupyter notebook with miniconda3. However, when I try to import scanpy, it gives an ImportError about the hdf5extension dll. When I look in the directory of the package *tables* though, I can see two files named hdf5.dll and hdf5extension.cp37-win_amd64.pyd (https://gyazo.com/a7d5a9d7d28756a8d82bc060b33b91ca). I assume that these are the files which should be imported, but I don't understand what's going wrong with the import.

I've used scanpy before on this system, but problems started showing up after I installed h5py via conda (not knowing that h5py is automatically included if you install scanpy via conda). So first I uninstalled h5py, which didn't work. Uninstalled and reinstalled miniconda3 twice, which did not work either.
Setting the $PATH variable manually didn't help either.

So then I looked into the file.py which is referred to in the traceback, and figured that there should be a file in the *tables* directory. I found the files, and thought that maybe they were named wrongly, so I tried changing the name, which did not work either. Downgrading python from 3.7.1 to 3.6.6 didn't work, nor creating a new env in conda with python 3.6.6 and installing all the required packages.

Working on Windows 7 64-bit, with conda 4.5.12 with the miniconda3 installer.

```
> Python 3.6.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 26 2018, 11:48:23) [MSC v
.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> import scanpy

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\scanpy\__init__.py", line 11, in 

> from . import tools as tl

> File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\scanpy\tools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>

> from .sim import sim

> File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\scanpy\tools\sim.py", line 19, in <module>

> from .. import readwrite

> File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\scanpy\readwrite.py", line 9,
in <module>

> import tables

> File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tables\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>

> from .file import File, open_file, copy_file

> File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tables\file.py", line 35, in <module>

> from . import hdf5extension

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: "The specified procedure could not be found" means that DLL could be loaded, but maybe not the proper version so a service is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem you had, twice.

This seemed to be a Windows-specific problem. My first solution was to **update my Visual Studio Version** which comes with C-Build Tools that might be required to run scanpy in some way(?). This worked fine for some time.

A few weeks later I had the same ImportError again. This time the only thing that helped was to **use an old version of h5py (2.8)**. Setting up a new Virtual Environment or resetting the Miniconda packages did not help, neither did [specifying the hdf5-DLL save location](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html) as a windows variable.

My suggestion is that the new hdf5 libraries in h5py Version 2.9 are not yet compatible with the current C-Compilers from Microsoft VS.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar problem, and I spend half a day on it.
To the point, the problem occured in the `tables` package, and so it is, at least for me.

The `tables` package was broken. I **uninstalled** it via conda and **delete** residual dirs(necessary, all dirs named after `tables`; the path can be got from the err info)
Then I **reinstall** it via 'pip', because my 'conda' channels don't have it.

An interesting thing is that 'pip' warmed me my h5py(2.8.0) is outdate and recommend me to update it to 2.10.0 for **scanpy**. (In fact, scanpy could work well then)

If you do so, congratulation, the `tables` broke again.
It seems that the h5py(2.10.0) would also install `tables`(but it has **errors in win10**)
Besides, if you get `ImportError: DLL load failed` for **h5py**, you should also use a similar pipe to reinstall it(delete manually).

Anyway, scanpy works in `win10 scanpy==1.7.1 h5py==2.8.0 tables==3.4.4`.
Maybe h5py 2.10.0 can also work if you reinstall `tables` at last.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble with scanpy, I uninstalled the anaconda several times 
my problem is as follows:

```
>>> import scanpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scanpy\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import tools as tl
  File "C:\software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scanpy\tools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._sim import sim
  File "C:\software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scanpy\tools\_sim.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .. import readwrite
  File "C:\software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scanpy\readwrite.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tables
  File "C:\Users\xiaokang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tables\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .utilsextension import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
```

At last I uninstalled the tables package and install the tables package again,then it works fine to me